# Send Reply with attachment using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been working with Microsoft graph API to receive and reply to the mail.
I've successfully received and send mails, but as per Graph API docs in reply only a comment can be passed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

I've developed the send mail code as shown below:-

```
IList<Recipient> messageToList = new List<Recipient>();
User currentUser = client.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result;

Recipient currentUserRecipient = new Recipient();

EmailAddress currentUserEmailAdress = new EmailAddress();

EmailAddress recepientUserEmailAdress = new EmailAddress();
currentUserEmailAdress.Address = currentUser.UserPrincipalName;

currentUserEmailAdress.Name = currentUser.DisplayName;
messageToList.Add(currentUserRecipient);
try

{

                ItemBody messageBody = new ItemBody();

                messageBody.Content = "A sample message from Ashish";

                messageBody.ContentType = BodyType.Text;


                Message newMessage = new Message();

                newMessage.Subject = "\nSample Mail From Ashish.";
                newMessage.ToRecipients = messageToList;
                newMessage.CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                    {
                        new Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "abc.xyz@xxxx.com"
                            }
                        }
                    };
                newMessage.Body = messageBody;




                client.Me.SendMail(newMessage, true).Request().PostAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("\nMail sent to {0}", currentUser.DisplayName);

}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nUnexpected Error attempting to send an email");
    throw;
}
```

This code is working fine!!

Can someone please share how I can Reply to a mail with attachment and mailbody like I'm able to do in Send mail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [create a reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0), [add the attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0), and then [send the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0). With the basic basic /reply endpoint you cant do it.

E.g.:

- Create the message draft using POST request

As a response you will get the whole message structure with id set to something like `AQMkADAwATMwMAItMTJkYi03YjFjLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA_hRKmxc6QpJks9QJkO5R50HAP6mz4np5UJHkvaxWZjGproAAAIBDwAAAP6mz4np5UJHkvaxWZjGproAAAAUZT2jAAAA`. Lets refer to it as {messageID}.

- After that you can create an attachment using POST request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{messageID}/attachments`

-After step 2 you will see created message in your mailbox Drafts folder. To send it use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{messageID}/send`

Hope it helps.

Comment: can we get a working example. As i Have all permission and followed the above steps, still getting error as " ErrorSendAsDenied Message: The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account., Cannot submit message"